# Javascript timers inside a function, clearTimeout doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript

Im having trouble getting javascript timers to work as intended when updating an old site to be more modern, it used to use iframes so refreshing the timers wasn't an issue, but now i want to use ajax to reload the div containing the timer, however it keeps counting at double speed, ive been reading about using clearTimeout which seems to be the solution im looking for, however i just can not get it to work at all, could anyone give me any advice on where to look to stop the times counting at double speed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = 60; // time in seconds to count down

function timer1() {

    if (var1 > 0) {
        var1 = var1 - 1;
    }
    else {
        var1 = "<font color=\"#90ee90\">GO</font>";
    }

    var countdown = document.all ? document.all["timer1"] : document.getElementById ? document.getElementById("timer1") : "";

    if (countdown) {
        countdown.innerHTML = var1 + " ";
        setTimeout( 'timer1()', 1000 );
    }
}

timer1();
</script>
```

I have already attempted `var stop= setTimeout('<?=$id; ?>()',1000);`
And then calling `clearTimeout(stop);`

However this seemed to completely ignore `clearTimeout` so i felt like I must have been doing it wrong

Comment: It is really unclear what is happening here - you should really consider rethinking this so you can create something that is much easier to read and maintain. Using PHP to name javascript variables in this way is not a forward thinking approach

Comment: It is hard to read whatever’s going on there. PHP and JavaScript are unrelated in this context. You have PHP that is rendering HTML that is JS, so the PHP doesn’t really matter. Please just post the HTML and JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, ive edited it to just show a more basic version of what im attempting to do

Comment: Why are you using `document.all` and `<font color="">`? I feel like I stepped back-in-time to 1999...

Comment: `setTimeout( 'timer1()', 1000 );` <-- Don't use strings to reference the function you want to call, just pass the function directly (**without** parens), like so: `setTimeout( timer1, 1000 );`

Comment: You may run into issues by using the same name for a global `function` as for a HTML element's `id=""` attributes. I suggest you give everything globally-distinct names/ids.

Comment: like i said its old code that im trying to bring up to scratch

Comment: You are asking about `clearTimeout`, but your code doesn't even involve it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) in this case.

> In case you want types: [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=7&ssc=26&pln=8&pc=29#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCWwDWARApgGwIYE8YF4YBGABjIG4BYAKAzVgjVDABMICYBWK2+ueALZoATgEkWHEjxoB6GTAAqIGNBAAHOAAs0-IcIA0MAFYBXaDGBYMGLfHYAzE2GAJwNR89dgVUdQsEiMAAUAJQAXDAAbiDwEgDeNDAWdFhiYFAikVZBCHriITxJzBAgdAB0GCAA5kEA5P56MCzgaLUFNAC+NO5OLvDg-MjB4VEx8YkW4OaYaELpHM3AJnNQZVX0AKJ0KwBCOOJ1uSJEbYUw8PbBAIQzKyEwwvQmwmDS1EkXwYzMbDAAfDASPcEu8kjBbmh0mUMgAPKAAYXAGXmhAAylBhPAwDVvuA2O1QUlcax2ABaQhEM5dUGYRgwEFg8HbSGraA4cqMKAABWE6hEUBwdVAlWEtUMtQAxABOEhoNAy04TJIQqGwhFIlkcWoAcQA8rUzkTfGoGiJQlTOt1qEcxBJCJzROlMtkEMhDK7UJhcASgA)

```css
#timer1 {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer1"></div>
<script type="module">

const tickDelay = 1000;
let seconds = 5;
let timerId = 0;

// To stop the timer, just call this function
function stopTimer () {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  console.log('Timer done');
}

function tick () {
  const element = document.getElementById('timer1');
  if (!element) return;

  if (seconds > 0) {
    element.textContent = String(seconds);
    seconds -= 1;
  }
  else {
    element.style.setProperty('color', '#90ee90');
    element.textContent = 'GO';
    stopTimer();
  }
}

timerId = setInterval(tick, tickDelay);

</script>
```